# Cannot initialize MVC template in Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code

I'm beginner to use Visual Studio Code.
I can run command "dotnet new"
but when I try to run command "dotnet new mvc", I get this error message:

[image: error message]

Update : I run suggest command then run "dotnet new mvc" again this is result.

[image]

Comment: So have you tried running the suggested command?

Comment: Looks like you don't have the MVC template installed, the command works fine for me. Go back to the installer perhaps?